# Is that possible to display sorted data in Ext.Util.Filter (extJs)

Tags: extjs

I am new to ExtJs. I would like to display the sorted data(alphabetical order) in the Filter window(extJs).

Could you please let me know if it is possible?

Comment: Can you post code or details of which component u have used?

Comment: What is for you a "Filter window" ?

Comment: "Filter Window" means where records are getting displayed. Example - list of  depart numbers.